# Is there any point to studying finite dimensional function spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

When people are studying function spaces, they really mean they are studying infinite dimensional function spaces, correct? And not just that, they want to study uncountable infinite dimensional function spaces? That's what functional analysis really means?

Comment: Finite dimensional spaces have lots of applications. Plus, it is always wise to understand finite dimensional objects before delving into infinite dimensional cases.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with function spaces.

Comment: numerical methods in e.g. PDEs largely works by projecting down to a finite dimensional subspace of functions. See FEM, Galerkin method...

Comment: I agree with the other commenters that finite dimensions are still important, but I also wanted to mention that spaces like $L^2([0,1])$ have countably infinite dimension in the Hilbert space sense.  So we don't restrict our attention to the uncountably infinite dimensional spaces.